# Design tips for synchronising signals through a VHDL pipeline

Tags: vhdl, pipeline, fpga

I am designing a video pixel data processing pipeline in VHDL which involves several steps including multiply and divide.
I want to keep signals synchronised so that I can e.g. maintain a sync signal and output it correctly at the end of the pipeline along with manipulated pixel data which has been through several processing stages.

I assume I want to use shift registers or something to delay signals by the right number of cycles so that the output is correct, but I'm looking for advice about good ways to design this, particularly as the number of pipeline stages for different signals may vary as I evolve the design.

Answer (score 2):

Good question.

I'm not aware of a complete solution but here are two partial strategies...

**Interconnecting components**... It would be really nice if a component could *export* a generic whose value was its pipeline depth. Unfortunately you can't, and dedicating a port to this seems silly (though it's probably workable; as it would be an integer constant, it would disappear in synthesis)

Failing that, pass IN a generic indicating the budget for this module. Inside the module, assert (severity FAILURE) if the budget can't be met... (this assert is checkable at synth time and at least Xilinx XST handles similar asserts)

Make the budget a hard number, and either assert if not equal to actual pipeline depth, or add pipe stages inside the module if the budget is too large, and only assert if the budget is too small.

That way you are connecting predictable modules, and the top level can perform pipeline arithmetic to balance things (e.g. passing a computed constant value to a programmable delay line)

**Within a component**... I use a single process, with registers represented as internal signals whose names reflect their pipe stage, `exponent_1, exponent_2, exponent_3` and so on. Within the process, the first section describes all the actions for the first cycle, the second section describes the second cycle, and so on. Typically the "easier" paths may be copied verbatim to the next pipe stage, just to sync them with the critical path. The process is fairly organised and easy to maintain.

I might break a 32-bit multiply down into 16*16 chunks and pipeline the partial product additions. The control this gives, USED to give better results than XST gave alone...

I know some people prefer variables within a process, and I use them for intermediate results in a pipe stage, but using signals I can describe the pipeline in its natural order (thanks to postponed assignment) whereas using variables, I would have to describe it backwards!

Answer (score 1):

I create a package for each of my major processing blocks, one of the constants in there is the processing delay of that block.  I can then connect that up to my general-purpose "delay-line" block which has a generic for the number of cycles.

Keeping that constant in "sync" with the actual implementation is best done by a self-checking testbench.

Answer (score 0):

Something to consider is delay lines (i.e. back to back registers) vs FIFOs.

Consider a module `X` with a pipeline delay `N`. FIFOs work well when there is a `N` is variable. The trick is remembering that you can only request new work when both the module and the FIFO can accept it. Ideally you size the FIFO so that it can contain the maximum number of items that `X` can work on concurrently, but sometimes that's not practical. For example, if your calculation includes accesses to a distant memory.

Another option is integrating the side channel (i.e. the path that your sync flag is taking) into the module `X` rather than it going outside. If you do this then if any part of the calculation has to stall, you can also stall the side channel and the two stay in sync. You can do this because you're in a scope that has all the necessary signals in it. Then all signals, whether used in the calculation or not, appear at the output at the same time.